# Aggegating rows in a numeric field

Tags: r

In R, I am trying to aggregate rows (just a simple count) in a numeric column.  I have a CSV file of zip codes, and would like to tally the rows by distinct zip code.

```
Properties <- read.csv("C://Users/Moss/Desktop/R/Data/DataExercise/data/List.csv", header=TRUE,sep=",")

ZipCode=(Properties$ZipCode)

summary(ZipCode)
```

Which produces:

```
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
20001   20002   20009   20071   20011   22314
```

However, I am looking for record counts by zip, like below, which I got to work when summarizing the "city" field (a string):

```
   Alexandria     Arlington       Ashburn      Bethesda   Centreville  College Park       Potomac Silver Spring   Takoma Park       Waldorf    Washington 
        2             1             1             2             1             1             1             1             1             1           188
```

I've tried using asString to convert zip code to string, but that hasn't seemed to work.

Comment: You can check the `table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting ZipCode into a factor.

```
ZipCode=as.factor(Properties$ZipCode)
summary(ZipCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` has really elegant group counting.

```
library(data.table)
Properties <- fread("./List.csv")
Properties[ , .N, by = ZipCode]
```